# Calculating integral using residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

My task is to find
$$\int_{|z|=6}tan(z)dz$$

So i was trying to find it using residue theorem. 

I found that 
$$Res(f(z),\frac{\pi}2+\pi n)= \frac{sinz}{-sinz}=-1$$

Now by the residue theorem 
$$\int_{|z|=6}tan(z)dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=0}^nRes(f(z),z_n)$$

My question is how do i calculate this? 

I have an infinite singular points.

 
Do I just set the $-1$ in the sum?  Won't i get an infinite residue, is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at the residue theorem again, you omitted the *winding number* term. Effectively, only the residues of singularities *inside* the contour contribute to the sum. That are finitely many.

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks for your help =]